# AWS KiB - bits or bytes?

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS describes a number of their performance metrics (e.g. [disk IO block size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-io-characteristics.html#ebs-io-iops)) in terms of KiB.

Does the "K" in KiB mean kilobytes or or kilobits?

Comment: Ki is for Kilo (1024), B is for bytes.

Comment: @Marcin, thanks for this.  Would you like to create an answer to this question?  If so, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KB` is **kilobytes**, which is unclear whether people are referring to 1000 bytes or 1024 bytes.

`KiB` is **kibibytes**, which is guaranteed to be 1024 bytes.

From [Byte - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units):

> A system of units **based on powers of 2** in which 1 kibibyte (KiB) is equal to 1,024 (i.e., 210) bytes is defined by international standard IEC 80000-13 and is supported by national and international standards bodies (BIPM, IEC, NIST). The IEC standard defines eight such multiples, up to 1 yobibyte (YiB), equal to 10248 bytes.